# clojure -- name conflicts in a defined record?

Tags: clojure, java-interop, clojure-java-interop

I have a misbehaving piece of code; when I name a record **MethodInfo**, it no longer overrides the **.toString** method correctly.

```
(defrecord MethodInfo [^clojure.lang.ISeq x ^clojure.lang.ISeq y]
  java.lang.Object
    (toString [x]
      (str (:x x))))
```

Running a simple test shows how this fails,

```
=> (.toString (new MethodInfo [1 2] [3]))
"sketch.compiler.main.sklojure1.MethodInfo@10e0d118"
```

whereas renaming the record to **A** shows the code behaving correctly,

```
=> (.toString (new A [1 2] [3]))
"[1 2]"
```

what am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your record works fine for me. I would recommend restarting the REPL as there might be some old code hanging around. Note also that you have direct access to fields in the record, so you can write

```
(defrecord MethodInfo [x y]
  Object
  (toString [_] (str x)))
```

instead of

```
(defrecord MethodInfo [x y]
  Object
  (toString [this] (str (:x this))))
```